# ndk build error with android namespace

Tags: android-ndk, cygwin

I'm using stock cygwin for ndk-build and im getting errors like

```
C:/Users/374565.NOAM/workspace/UltraSoundJNI/jni/utils/Errors.h:24: 
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'android'
```

this line is :

```
namespace android{
```

this happens in multiple files, how do i fix this?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to compile C++ code as pure C.

Comment: wow, I would have never have guessed that was the reason.. c has namespaces.. make it an answer and ill give it to you.

Comment: No C doesn't have namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to compile C++ code as pure C.